# My program stops with no errror, what did I do wrong?

Tags: c++, input

I have no idea why, but my code just stops at the 2nd for loop in the cin line, if it loops more than 1 time.

Can you help me?
This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>//Julianne
using namespace std;
    
int main(){
    int a;
    
    cin >>  a;
    int bezorgen[a];
    
    int afhalen[a];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        cin >> bezorgen[i];
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++){   
        cin >> afhalen[j];    
    }        
    
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Sorry for my grammar mistakes.

Comment: Ignoring the variable-length-array-in-C++ part, this behaves the way I'd expect on entering 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 on separate lines.  So, what are you entering?

Answer (score 1):

C++'s declaration
`int name[N]` is only valid when N is constant. For dynamic sized array (which is in your case dynamic, cause array size comes from user input) you can use:

1. C++ `std::vector<int>`
2. `int *name = new int[a]`

First one is the list, not an array. So you need to .push_back elements before they can be accesed.

Second one is an array, and accessed just like common array. **Be careful** with that, because you need to free memory when it's not needed anymore, call `delete [] name;` at the end of your program for every `new type[size]` you've done.